# R programming for data segmentation

Tags: r

I have data from an accelerometer device with `x`, `y`, `z` components table. And on a particular column I want to select data segments from that column alone using R code.

How can I achieve this: lets say the column has these numbers

`1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0`

And I want my result to be subsets like this

`(1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5, 1), (2, 3, 0, 4, 5)`

stored in a variables that I can reuse. Essentially I am taking data segments between three consecutive zeros. How can I achieve this in R programming.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: If your data is strings, it's possible with regex: `lapply(strsplit(strsplit('1,2,3,0,0,0,3,4,5,1,0,0,0,2,3,0,4,5,0,0,0', '(,?0,0?){2,}')[[1]], ','), type.convert)`. If it's a vector, check out `rle`.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @ Patrick Mevzek - path <- "C:/Users/Data ML Research/UCI/Data2017/"
 setwd(path)

 df<- fread ("checkdata.csv")
 head(df)
 
 df$Rvec <- sqrt(df$x^2 + df$y^2 + df$z^2)
 df$diff <- ave (df$Rvec, FUN = function(x) c (0, diff(x)))
  
 k <- 1:length(df$diff)
 
 cols<-names(df)[1:5]
 df[,(cols) := round(.SD, 2), .SDcols=cols]
 head(df)

Comment: @alistaire Thanks.

Comment: @kvantour. noted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel there are better answers, but meanwhile you can try this:

```
# Simulating your data
column <- c(1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0)

# The actual answer
columnS <- paste(column, collapse="-") # Using - as vector token separator
columnS <- gsub("0-0-0", "=", columnS) # Using = as list token separator
fs <- strsplit(columnS, "=") # Creating the list
fs <- strsplit(fs[[1]], "-") # Creating the vectors of numbers inside each list
fs <- lapply(fs, function(x){return(as.numeric(x[x!=""]))}) # Casting to numeric
print(fs)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. It does help.

Answer (score 1):

If what you have is a vector, the following will do it.
It uses `rle`, `inverse.rle` and a standard `cumsum` trick to split the data into the segments you need.

```
x <- c(1,2,3,0,0,0,3,4,5,1,0,0,0,2,3,0,4,5,0,0,0)

r <- rle(x == 0)
r$values[r$lengths < 3] <- FALSE
s <- split(x, cumsum(c(0, abs(diff(!inverse.rle(r))))))
s[!sapply(s, function(.s) length(.s) >= 3 && all(.s == 0))]
#$`0`
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#$`2`
#[1] 3 4 5 1
#
#$`4`
#[1] 2 3 0 4 5
```

Comment: Thanks really appreciate